# Getting the data from a CGRect object

Tags: ios, cgrect

I know that a CGRect consists of 4 floats. How can I get those floats from a given CGRect object?

I searched for CGRect's class reference and found nothing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like this: (assuming a previously defined `CGRect` called `myRect`)

```
CGFloat x = myRect.origin.x;
CGFloat y = myRect.origin.y;
CGFloat height = myRect.size.height;
CGFloat width = myRect.size.width;
```

Answer (score 2):

The reason you didn't find anything is that simply CGRect is not a class.

The documentation is right [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGGeometry/Reference/reference.html).

I hope it helps. :)